# Are there some results which count $\sum_{p\in [x/2,x]} \log p$ or $\sum_{p\in [x,y]} \log p$ for for $x$ and $y$ positive and real?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

I have seen the prime number theorem and on the of versions I know is that $\sum_{p\leq x} \log p=O(x)$ (I am counting over primes here and in the rest of the post).  Are there any similar results for say, $\displaystyle \sum_{\substack{p\in [x/2, \hspace{0.1em} x]\\p \text{ prime}}} \log p$ or or $\displaystyle \sum_{\substack{p\in [x,y]\\p \text{ prime}}} \log p$ in general? Also, are there some estimates on $\displaystyle \sum_{p\in[x,y]}\frac{\log p}{p}$ or some $[x,y]$? Perhaps, these are not very hard questions but I don't know how to get good bounds without counting up to $y$ and subtracting from it the count up to $x$. Thank you!

Comment: I think the usual name for this sort of thing is "(a) prime number theorem in short intervals". You should have a look at the following survey by Yildirim as a starting point: http://www.math.boun.edu.tr/instructors/yildirim/paper/paper9.pdf

Comment: I take it that, even though you never say so, $p$ is meant to run over primes.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, edited to reflect that.

Comment: @asahay, thanks for pointing me to the survey!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the various forms of Mertens' theorems and the prime number theorem, you can easily generate bounds for your sums. That is, if you have an approximation for $\sum_{n\leq y}a(n)$ and $\sum_{n\leq x}a(n)$, then subtracting one from the other, you get an approximation for $\sum_{x<n\leq y}a(n)$. However, better results are available by more advanced techniques like zero density estimates for $\zeta(s)$ or sieve methods. For example, [Huxley (1972)](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/download/PPN356556735_0015/PPN356556735_0015___log17.pdf) proved that if $c\in(7/12,1]$ is fixed and $x\to\infty$, then for any $y\in[x+x^c,2x]$ we have
$$\frac{1}{y-x}\sum_{x<p\leq y}\log p\to 1.$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It's very helpful.

Comment: @user96343: If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!

Comment: of course! Done.